# Why am I getting an infinite loop when updating condition in a function

Tags: java, while-loop, infinite-loop

I'm updating the *nums[i]* variable in my function and I even made it return the array instead of it being a void function but I'm still getting an infinite loop

```
class Solution {
    public void moveZeroes(int[] nums) {
        for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
            while(nums[i]==0){
                nums=shift(i,nums);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public int[] shift(int index, int[]nums){
        for(int i=index;i<nums.length-1;i++){
            nums[i]=nums[i+1];
        }
        nums[nums.length-1]=0;
        return nums;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what the code should do? Maybe also with an example of the input and the desired output.

Comment: 1)  Consider what happens when you call `moveZeros` on the array `[0]`.  2) If you still can't see the problem, read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/)

Comment: It is also worth noting that `shift` doesn't create a new array.  It returns the reference to its input array.  So the `nums=shift(i,nums);` is actually doing the same thing as `shift(i,nums);`

Answer (score 0):

What `int[]` are you passing it? Imagine what happens if you pass an array with all zero values. `while(nums[i] == 0)` will always be true because no matter how you shift it, there will be a zero at the start of the array, and so an infinite loop. Keep this in mind when looking at the line `nums[nums.length - 1] = 0;`. This line is adding a zero at the end of the `nums` array each time `shift()` is called. So, what happens when you reach the end of your original for loop (when i = nums.length - 1)? `nums[i]` will reference the 0 you placed at the end of your array in the `shift()` function. The code will call that function again, **then do the same exact thing.** `i` is still nums.length - 1 because the iteration of the for loop hasn't finished, so `i` hasn't been incremented. That's your infinite loop.

If you'd like additional help with the methods, please comment better descriptions of what the code is supposed to exactly.

Comment: I'm realizing my solution isn't very effective for that reason, but what's interesting is that the problem is in the nums[nums.length-1]=0; part of the function. I can't figure out why.

Comment: @user722214 - I suggested in the comments on your question that you read two links, if you were still baffled by this.  They describe important techniques for finding bugs in your code.  In particular the Rubber Duck Debugging technique ... which is basically about gaining an understanding of what your code does by reading it and *explaining it to yourself*.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code I think you are trying to move zeroes present in the array to the right end. You can simply do that by changing your while loop to an if condition or using break statement after you are calling shift function. You are getting infinite loop because lets take an example of array with elements {1,2,0}. when your code reaches the end of the array your shift function will not be able to move that zero so your nums[i] will remain zero.

Comment: I'm realizing my solution isn't very effective for that reason, but what's interesting is that the problem is in the nums[nums.length-1]=0; part of the function. I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

You should stop your iterations dynamically depends on numbers of zeros.
[image]

Add another int counter that counting the zeros and then stop once you are in zeros area

```
   /**
     * The entry point of application.
     *
     * @param args the input arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] ints = new int[10];
        ints[0]=1;
        ints[1]=0;
        ints[2]=0;
        ints[3]=1;
        ints[4]=1;
        ints[5]=0;
        ints[6]=1;
        ints[7]=0;
        ints[8]=1;
        ints[9]=1;
        moveZeroes(ints);
        for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(String.format("%d: %d",i,ints[i]));
        }


    }
    public static void moveZeroes(int[] nums) {
        int zeros=0;
        for(int i=0;i<nums.length-zeros;i++){
            while(nums[i]==0){
                zeros++;
                nums=shift(i,nums);
            }
        }
    }

    public static int[] shift(int index, int[]nums){
        for(int i=index;i<nums.length-1;i++){
            nums[i]=nums[i+1];
        }
        nums[nums.length-1]=0;
        return nums;
    }
```

Output:

```
0: 1
1: 1
2: 1
3: 1
4: 1
5: 1
6: 0
7: 0
8: 0
9: 0
```